# R built-in Breusch-Pagan Test getting different results from manual Calculation

Tags: r, regression, heteroscedasticity, breusch-pagan, lagrange-multipliers

I was using the following code to calculate the bp-test (eaef.csv can be found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/mpo1jbs/data/eaef.csv?attredirects=0&d=1)).

```
student.dat <- read.csv("eaef.csv", header=T, sep=",")
attach(student.dat)
lnearnings <- log(earnings) ; weightsq <- weight^2
student.lm2 <- lm(lnearnings~schooling+height+weight+weightsq, student.dat)
bptest(student.lm2,~schooling*height*weight*weightsq+
         I(schooling^2)+I(height^2)+I(weight^2)+I(weightsq^2))
```

the output is:

```
data:  student.lm2
BP = 20.338, df = 18, p-value = 0.3141
```

However, if I construct the test manually:

```
#direct construction of bptest
aux.lm <- lm(I(residuals(student.lm2)^2)~ schooling*height*weight*weightsq+
               I(schooling^2)+I(height^2)+I(weight^2)+I(weightsq^2))
pchisq(nrow(student.dat) * summary(aux.lm)$r.squared, 19, lower.tail=F)
```

I got different p-value `0.3745022`.

The way I construct the manual test is by following the definitions in [this](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxtcG8xamJzfGd4OjZiM2I3YzkxYmY2ZWJiMDE) slide (page 38).

Any idea why is there a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used 19 degrees of freedom while `bptest()` used only 18. The reason for this discrepancy is that you cannot include the identical regressors `weightsq` and `I(weight^2)` in the auxiliary regression. Well, you can, obviously, but only one coefficient can be estimated while the other is aliased and set to `NA`:

```
R> coef(aux.lm)[c("weightsq", "I(weight^2)")]
##    weightsq I(weight^2) 
## 0.005487211          NA
```

Thus, using the degrees of freedom only from the non-aliased coefficients gives the same results as `bptest()`:

```
pchisq(nrow(student.dat) * summary(aux.lm)$r.squared,
  sum(!summary(aux.lm)$aliased) - 1, lower.tail = FALSE)
## [1] 0.3141148
```